# Reference containing folder of nant script?

Tags: nant

In NANT,if I write a path, how could I , instead of writing "c:\documents and settings" etc, reference the containing folder of the nant script?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current directory of the nant script by calling the `project::get-base-directory()` function.

[project::get-base-directory](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/functions/project.get-base-directory%28%29.html)

You can also get the current directory by calling the `directory::get-current-directory function()` function.

[directory::get-current-directory](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/functions/directory.get-current-directory%28%29.html)